# Why entityframework Remove & RemoveRange return type not void or bool

Tags: c#, entity-framework

While using entityframework I have seen the syntax for methods `Remove` and `RemoveRange` are

```
public virtual TEntity Remove(TEntity entity);

public virtual IEnumerable<TEntity> RemoveRange(IEnumerable<TEntity> entities);
```

Simply we expect return type to be a `bool`; That tells if entity successfully removed or not.
Now if  it does return those values, there might be a situations where it can be useful.

I think `RemoveRange` would return list of entities that are successfully removed. In that case one can check which entities are deleted from list as

```
var db = new MyDataContext();
var itemsToRemove = db.MySet.Where(x => !x.active);
var removedItems = db.MySet.RemoveRange(itemsToRemove);
```

and use list of `removedItems` to display items removed sucessfully.

I do not understand if I should catch that return values. Are there any specific scenarios where return values of these methods required to be catched and used?

Comment: `public bool Remove(TEntity entity)`  .... it returns Bool
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb337024.aspx

Comment: @ShekharPankaj no, `DBSet<TEntity>.Remove` returns `TEntity`

Comment: @ShekharPankaj, I expect you notice word entityframewok

Comment: sorry just Noticed, I will get an appointment from Eye Doctor

Comment: Is [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb337024%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) the method we are talking about?

Comment: @MobyDisk, it's not. Please read above comments.

Comment: https://entityframework.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/EntityFramework/DbSet`.cs - this one

Answer (score 4):

If you look at [code](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/EntityFramework/DbSet%60.cs), you'll see that it returns the same object:

```
public virtual TEntity Remove(TEntity entity)
{
  Check.NotNull<TEntity>(entity, "entity");
  this.GetInternalSetWithCheck("Remove").Remove((object) entity);
  return entity;
}
```

I think, it made mostly just because they can do it. So, you can not catch result after `Remove` method.

But I can image such case: you need to do something with the entity after removing:

```
void LogEntity<TEntity>(TEntity entity)
{
    //...log
}

void Method(User user)
{
    LogEntity(context.Set<User>().Remove(user));
}
```

Instead of:

```
void Method(User user)
{
    context.Set<User>().Remove(user);
    LogEntity(user);
}
```

Comment: That one is looks fine to me. +1